# Can we use firebase dynamic links without the page.link domain?

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

When we're using Firebase dynamic links do we have to use the page.links domain hosted be google or can we use our own host and domain?

I want the functionality of installing an app from a link and then processing the custom url on first run but I want the apple-app-site-association file to be hosted on my own server.

Is this possible?
If not, is this functionality possible without firebase or branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you can only use a subdomain of `page.link` on Firebase Dynamic Links but please to file a feature request to bring your own domain name: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/